# How can I fit a system of differential equations to data without setting/assuming an initial condition?

Tags: python, optimization, ode, scipy-optimize, data-fitting

I am a biology student working on some population dynamics problems. The data I have is only the sum of populations of predators and prey in the environment over time. I have two coupled differential equations that describe the dynamics of each population. What I would like to do is to fit these equations to the data such that the error between predicted and measured (total) population is minimized.

The equations are as follows:

> dx/dt = A*x - B*x - C*x
> dy/dt = A*y + B*x

And I would like to minimize the cost function defined as follows:

> ((x+y) - data)<sup>2</sup>

Note that I do not have individual x and y data, but only T=x+y. Hence I would like to find the best guess for x and y at initial time t0.

The code I currently use for this is:

```
days = np.array([0,50,90,130,190,240,281,310,350,450])
data = np.array([51,48,46,44,43,52,52,54,56,97])

def system_ode(populations, time, params):
    x = populations[0]
    y = populations[1]

    A = params[0]
    B = params[1]
    C = params[2]

    dx_dt = x*(A - B - C)
    dy_dt = x*A + y*B

    return [dx_dt, dy_dt]

def cost_func(params, time, data):

    init_populations = [data[0],0]

    time = np.linspace(days[0], days[-1], num = len(days))

    predicted_data = odeint(system_ode, init_populations, time, args=(params,))

    sum_pops = np.sum(predicted_data, axis=1)
    cost = np.sum(sum_pops - data)**2

    return cost


init_params = [0.3, 0.3, 0.3] #initial parameter guesses

opt_result = minimize(cost_func, init_params, args=(days, data))
opt_params = opt_result.x.tolist()

# now integrating with the optimized parameters
init_populations = [data[0],0]
time = np.linspace(days[0], days[-1], 100)

pred_data_opt = odeint(system_ode, init_populations, time, args=(opt_params,))

# Plotting 
plt.plot(days, data[:], 'bo', label='Measured Total')
plt.plot(time, pred_data_opt[:, 0], 'r-', label='Predicted X')
plt.plot(time, pred_data_opt[:, 1], 'b-', label='Predicted Y')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Population')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

This results in a very sub-optimal fit as seen in the graph, but I'm not sure why. In addition, I am currently forcing the curve to go through the first point (as i provide the initial conditions and assume that the population of Y is 0 at t0). Is there a way of fitting these equations without this assumption?

[image: The resulting fit and measured data]use cod

Comment: You can add the initial conditions as an additional two params to consider in your minimization.

Comment: Additionally, I think your cost has the order of operations wrong. You want `np.sum((sum_props - data)**2)` assuming you want the sum of square error.

Comment: I've tried to do this with these changes, but the problem is very sensitive to initial conditions. For example, your data only changes by 3 over 50 days, while scaling with population. Assuming a starting `x` population of 50, you're looking around `A - B - C = -0.001`.

Comment: Yes, I'd also try first some parameter sets without the minimizer, but please check once more your differential equation. Is it really as you stated? Actually, in your code, you swapped A and by for dy/dt compared to the description above.

Comment: .. and your predicted data is equidistant in time, while the input data isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I did a couple of things:

- I tried some parameters manually to get into the right area. The scaling of the parameters was important.
- The ODE was implemented wrongly for dy/dt. A and B were swapped.
- As noted by Michael Cao in the comments to the question, I modified the square of sums into a sum of squares.
- Also based on input from Michael, I added the initial conditions as parameters.
- Then I changed the minimization method from default to Powell. If I would set it up from scratch, I'd recommend to use `least_squares` instead of `minimize`. It's more robust as being more specific to this problem.
- I changed the time evaluation points in the objective to match the measured time instances.
- I added the graph for the total X + Y into the figure.

Maybe more ... Here is the code:

```
 import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

days = np.array([0, 50, 90, 130, 190, 240, 281, 310, 350, 450])
data = np.array([51, 48, 46, 44, 43, 52, 52, 54, 56, 97], float)


def system_ode(populations, time, params):
    x, y = populations
    A, B, C = params

    dx_dt = x * (A - B - C)
    dy_dt = x * B + y * A
    return [dx_dt, dy_dt]


def cost_func(params, time, data):
    init_populations = params[3:]

    predicted_data = odeint(system_ode, init_populations, days,
                            args=(params[:3],))
    sum_pops = np.sum(predicted_data, axis=1)
    return np.sum((sum_pops - data) ** 2)


# A, B, x[0], y[0]
init_params = [2e-3, 2e-3, 1e-2, data[0] / 2, data[0] / 2]

opt_result = minimize(cost_func, init_params, args=(days, data),
                      method="Powell")
opt_params = opt_result.x.tolist()
print("Optimal parameters and initial state: ", opt_params)

# now integrating with the optimized parameters
init_populations = opt_params[3:]
time = np.linspace(days[0], days[-1], 100)

pred_data_opt = odeint(system_ode, init_populations, time,
                       args=(opt_params[:3], ))
sum_pops = np.sum(pred_data_opt, axis=1)

# Plotting
plt.plot(days, data[:], 'ko', label='Measured Total')
plt.plot(time, pred_data_opt[:, 0], 'r-', label='Predicted X')
plt.plot(time, pred_data_opt[:, 1], 'b-', label='Predicted Y')
plt.plot(time, sum_pops, 'k-', label='Predicted Total')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Population')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Comment:**
The calculated initial conditions are x = 26.66.. and y = 22.99.., and the differential equation is solved continuously. So we must assume that non-integer populations can exist. Well, else the differential equation had to be formulated in terms of probabilities.

Comment: I tried this, and it works! Thank you very much. I think this system is super sensitive to the initial guesses of the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can SOLVE the equations exactly (in terms of unknowns x0 and y0). You do not need a numerical integrator.

The first gives x = x0.exp[(A-B-C)t].

Adding the equations together and then substituting for x you will get an equation for (x+y), which, after considerable rearrangement, solves as:

x+y=(x0+y0+(C/(B+C))x0.(exp[-(B+C)t]-1) )exp[At]

You can now fit this to your data for five parameters: x0, y0, A, B and C.

I found this system extremely stiff, and I had to start with very small values of the parameters.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import minimize

days = np.array( [  0, 50, 90, 130, 190, 240, 281, 310, 350, 450 ], dtype=float )
data = np.array( [ 51, 48, 46,  44,  43,  52,  52,  54,  56,  97 ], dtype=float )

def sumSquares( params, days, data ):
    x0, y0, A, B, C = params
    xplusy = ( x0 + y0  + C / ( B + C ) * x0 * ( np.exp( -( B + C ) * days ) - 1.0 ) ) * np.exp( A * days )
    cost = np.sum( ( xplusy - data ) ** 2 )
    return cost


init_params = 5 * [ 1.0e-5 ]
opt_result = minimize( sumSquares, init_params, args=( days, data ) )

x0, y0, A, B, C = opt_result.x
print( "x0, y0 =", x0, y0 )
print( "A, B, C =", A, B, C )

t = np.linspace( days[0], days[-1], 100 )
xplusy = ( x0 + y0  + C / ( B + C ) * x0 * ( np.exp( -( B + C ) * t ) - 1.0 ) ) * np.exp( A * t )
x = x0 * np.exp( ( A - B - C ) * t )
y = xplusy - x


# Plotting 
plt.plot( days, data, 'ko', label='Measured Total')
plt.plot( t, x, 'r-', label='Predicted X')
plt.plot( t, y, 'b-', label='Predicted Y')
plt.plot( t, xplusy, 'g-', label='Predicted X+Y')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Population')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Output:

```
x0, y0 = 13.310517227402412 36.53439562225955
A, B, C = 0.009646407014832555 -0.02848020844928538 0.03910220448046631
```

[image]

Comment: This is also a good solution as these diff. eq. are really linear and solvable as shown. If you use this, consider strongly to use `scipy.optimize.least_squares` instead of `minimize`. It's really much more robust when applicable.

Comment: @user2573593, it would be useful if you could check what you have written as equations and what you have coded in system_ode(). It's soluble either way, just that the two solutions are going to be different!

Comment: Right yes, i had made a mistake in the equations while coding. THank you for pointing that out and for the solution!